# ::ms-thumb pseudo element behaviour after dragging

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

Has anyone had any experience styling and controlling the behaviour of the ms-thumb pseudo-element on the input range control in IE11?

If the control is taller than the thumb pseudo-element the thumb sticks to the top after dragging and doesn't return to it's original position.

[Here's an example of the behaviour on codepen and the css being used (requires IE11 or Project Spartan/Edge)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqvXgq)

```
.c-slider{
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  padding:0px;
}

/*Slider Specific Styling*/

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  width: 30px;
  height:7px;
  border:1px solid #0066CC;
  background-color:#0066CC;
  cursor:pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb:active{
  background-color:green;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb:hover{        
    height: 60px;
    width: 30px;    
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #A1A1A1;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
     background: #EBF5FF;
}


/*Slider Reset Css*/
input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* Hides the slider so that custom slider can be made */
    width: 100%; /* Specific width is required for Firefox. */
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none; /* Removes the blue border. You should probably do some kind of focus styling for accessibility reasons though. */
}


input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent; /* Hides the slider so custom styles can be added */
    border-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting top and bottom margins on the thumb equal to half the difference between the thumb height and the control height.

Comment: Would you mind creating a basic demo to validate and examine your proposition?